# Excel weird timestamp. How to convert it back to normal timestamp?

Tags: excel, actionscript-3, timestamp

I'm using Flash and as3 to convert Excel timestamp to normal timestamp, thus - to normal date.

I have this function

```
    public static function dateFromExcel(date:Number):Date {
         return new Date(1970, 0, 1 + (date - 25569));
    }
```

This works fine if I need only a correct date (year, month, date). But now I have a time, that  is displayed in Excel as follows:

```
    1:00:00
```

But the real value of the cell is:

```
    1/1/1900 1:00:00 AM
```

That's a autoformatted by Excel. Now, when I read Excell with as3 code, as with dates, I get decimal number. For this time I get this:

```
    1.0416666666666667
```

When I run the same function on this decimal number, I get this:

```
    Mon Jan 1 00:00:00 GMT+0200 1900
```

Which is obviously incorrect.
As I get, with that function I can only work with the date and not the time. Can anyone look at this and figure out, how to get the time to work with this function too?

Answer (score 2):

While I was writting this question, I figured it out myself.
It is documented, that excel timestamp is the total days starting from 1900/01/01.
So this means, that the numbers after the decimal point is the percentage of the one day. For me, I just multiplied that number with the total count of seconds in one day and got the correct time. The function is as follows:

```
    public static function dateFromExcel(date:Number):Date {
    var sec_ind_day:Number = 86400;
    var secs:Number = sec_ind_day*date%1;
    var _d:Date = new Date(1970, 0, 1 + (date - 25569));
    return new Date(_d.fullYear, _d.month, _d.date, _d.hours, _d.minutes, secs);
}
```

So, anyone who got the same issue, this should work fine.